# Different types of critical point $(S.L Ross) $ Article 13.3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am studying critical points in differential equation:

Consider the system of differential equations

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = ax + by$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = cx + dy$$

where $a,b,c,d$ are real constants such that $$B=\left | \begin{matrix}
 a & b\\
c  & d\\ \end {matrix}\right | \neq 0  $$

Suppose $x(t) = A e^{\lambda t}$ and $y(t) = B e^{\lambda t}$

If they satisfy the given system we get

$$\lambda A e^{\lambda t} = A a e^{\lambda t} + B b e^{\lambda t}$$

and  $$ \lambda B e^{\lambda t} = A c e^{\lambda t} + B d e^{\lambda t}$$

Equating the coefficients of $e^{\lambda t}$ of both equations, we obtain

$$ A( a - \lambda ) + Bb = 0 $$

and

$$ Ac + B( d - \lambda )   = 0 $$

Thus the linear system has non trivial solution iff $$B=\left | \begin{matrix}
 a - \lambda & b\\
c  & d - \lambda\\ \end {matrix}\right | = 0  $$

implies we get $ \lambda^2 - (a + d) \lambda + ad - bc = 0$, where $\lambda \neq 0$

There are two non zeroes roots of the quadratic equation says $ \lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$

For $\lambda = \lambda_1$, the solution can be written as 
$$ x(t) = A_1 e^{\lambda_1 t}$$

$$ y(t) = B_1 e^{\lambda_1 t}$$

For $\lambda = \lambda_2$ , the solution can be written as

$$ x(t) = A_2 e^{\lambda_2 t}$$

$$ y(t) = B_2 e^{\lambda_2 t}$$

Thus the general solution of the given differential equation system is

$$ x(t) =c_1 A_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} + c_2 A_2 e^{\lambda_2} t$$

$$ y(t) = c_1B_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} + c_2 B_2 e^{\lambda_2 t}$$

Here $A_1 , A_2 , B_1, B_2$ are definite constants and $c_1 , c_2$ are arbitrary constants.

Definition : Let $P$ be the path of the given  system and let $x = f(t)$ and $ y = g(t)$ be a solution of which represent path $P$. Let $(0,0)$ be the critical point of the given system. We shall say that the path $P$ approaches the critical point $(0,0)$ as $ t \rightarrow + \infty$ if $\lim_{t \rightarrow + \infty} f(t) = 0$ and $\lim_{t \rightarrow + \infty} g(t) = 0$

Definition of Node : The critical point $(0 , 0)$ is called a node if there exists a neighbourhood of $(0 , 0)$ such that every path $P$ has the following properties

(a) $P$ is defined for all $ t > t_o$ $( \forall t < t_o) $ for some fixed number $t_o$

(b) $P$ approaches $( 0 , 0)$ as $ t \rightarrow + \infty$ or $( t \rightarrow - \infty)$

(c) $P$ enters $(0 , 0)$ as $ t \rightarrow + \infty$ or $( t \rightarrow - \infty)$

> > If $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are unequal and of same sign, then the critical point $(0 ,0)$ of the linear differential equation system is a node ?

We assume that $\lambda _1$ and $\lambda _2 $ are both negative and take $\lambda_1 < \lambda_2 < 0$

I have find out the general solution of the given system is

$$ x(t) = c_1 A_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} + c_2 A_2 e^{\lambda_2} t$$

$$ y(t) = c_1 B_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} + c_2 B_2 e^{\lambda_2 t}$$

Take $c_2 = 0$ or $c_1 =0 $ we obtain the solution $ x = ky$ which represents the half line.

I have a doubt in this point.

If $ c_1$ and $c_2$ are non zero, then the general solution represents the non rectilinear paths. Why this is true and how does the general solution satisfy the first property of the definition of node.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for editting Mattos

Comment: I've read your actual question a few times (starting from the "If $c_1$ and $c_2$ are non zero, ...") but I still don't quite understand what you mean? Could you make an edit to your post and try and explain it more clearly (and add more information perhaps) and I'll do my best to answer it.

Comment: I want to ask that how critical point $(0,0)$ satisfy the three property of the definition of the node if $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ ar  e real , unequal and same sign.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are asking to be honest? If $\lambda_{1,2}$ both have the same sign, then both eigenvalues are either pointing towards (if positive) _or_ away from (if negative) the critical point, which satisfies definitions $(b)$ and $(c)$.

Comment: Definitly you are saying correctly that the critical point satisfying the definition (b) and (c) but How will satisfy definition (a).

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to be more clear on what you mean by "How will satisfy definition"..